# Computing the first derivative in x, y ,and z

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, webmathematica, differentials

I have the following function:

```
f:=x^3+yz+z^2x;
```

I need to compute the first derivative in `x`, `y` , and `z`  in the 6 following points:

```
  %/.{x->1,y->3,z->0}                            
  %/.{x->0,y->1,z->2}                            
  %/.{x->0,y->0,z->6}                           
  %/.{x->7,y->6,z->8}                            
  %/.{x->7,y->7,z->9}                              
  %/.{x->6,y->9,z->3}
```

Comment: In your function definition you need a space in order to indicate multiplication. "yz" is a symbol. You should have typed "y z" or "y*z".

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is a duplicate. I just note that `Grad` can provide all the partial derivatives in one step. I just post this not to encourage all multiple rule lists but to limit typing:

```
rep = {{x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> 0},
   {x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 2},
   {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 6},
   {x -> 7, y -> 6, z -> 8},
   {x -> 7, y -> 7, z -> 9},
   {x -> 6, y -> 9, z -> 3}};
f := x^3 + y z + z^2 x;
```

So,

```
TableForm[(Grad[f, {x, y, z}] /. #) & /@ rep, 
 TableHeadings -> {#[[All, 2]] & /@ 
    rep, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(x\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(y\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(z\)]\)"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

another way:

```
f = x^3 + y z + z^2 x;
grad[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[f, {x, y, z}];
mat = {{1, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 6}, {7, 6, 8}, {7, 7, 9}, {6, 9,3}};
grad[##] & @@@ mat
{{3, 0, 3}, {4, 2, 1}, {36, 6, 0}, {211, 8, 118}, {228, 9, 133}, {117,3, 45}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try using

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^3 + y*z + z^2*x

Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]

%/.{x->1,y->3,z->0}   

Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, z]

Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, z]
```

Comment: This is the way to go.  In fact, the replacement is not even necessary.  Just do:  `Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][1,3,0]`, etc...